# How to make my discord.js-bot log the edit of a message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make my bot log when and what has been edited in a message.

This is the code of the listener:

```js
client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage,message) => {
    client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage,message) => {
const MessageLog = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id ==='802262886624919572');
var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setAuthor(message.author.username).catch(console.error)
.setTimestamp(new Date())
.setColor('#392B47')
.addFields(
    {name: 'original:',value: oldMessage},
    {name: 'edit:', value: newMessage}    );
MessageLog.send(embed);
 });
```

So far he is having the problem fetching the message.author.username
I have tried defyning the message with oldmessage and newmessage, but same problem there.

Console log: TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that `message` is undefined.
The problem is that the `messageUpdate` event doesnt give the last message as a parameter (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageUpdate)
To fix this you could replace the message in `message.author.username` with newMessage.

I also found another problem with your code, when you add the fields to the embed, you should use `newMessage.content` as the value, instaid of just `newMessage`

Answer (score 0):

First thing, [the 'messageUpdate' event has two arguments: oldMessage and newMessage](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageUpdate).

Second thing, you can't use `.catch` on a MessageEmbed. So instead, we will remove that part of code and replace it with an user check.

Third thing, you don't need to chain messageUpdate events.

Fourth thing, you can call setTimestamp empty as it will default to `Date.now()` [(source)](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=setTimestamp)

So lets fix your code:

```js
client.on('messageUpdate', (oldMessage, newMessage) => { // Old message may be undefined
   if (!oldMessage.author) return;
   const MessageLog = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id ==='802262886624919572');
var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setAuthor(newMessage.author.username)
.setTimestamp()
.setColor('#392B47')
.addFields(
    {name: 'original:',value: oldMessage},
    {name: 'edit:', value: newMessage}    );
MessageLog.send(embed);
}
```

Comment: I had to remove the user-check, but it is sending a message into my log-channel now.
It still doesn't display the message.author in the embed and somehow also doesn't fetch the oldmessage so they both just display "null" unfortunately

Comment: Can you recheck the code @Sparkly? thanks.